# WebForms model binding and nested properties

Tags: asp.net, resharper, model-binding

I'm using model binding in ASP.NET 4.5, and it seems like nested properties are finally supported in data fields. Here is an example:

```
<asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableViewState="True"
    ID="LogLines" ItemType="LogLine" runat="server"
    SelectMethod="GetLogLines">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Time" HeaderText="Time (UTC)">
            <HeaderStyle Width="14em"/>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="User.Username" HeaderText="User">
            <HeaderStyle Width="8em"/>
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

User.Username is a nested property and I'm displaying it directly in the GridView. Everything works as expected, except ReSharper flags it as an error and says "Cannot resolve symbol 'User.Username'". When I reported it as a bug they said using nested properties is undocumented behavior and won't be supported in their product. They pointed me to documentation that was pre model binding, so I'm not sure if they are correct or not.

I'm having a really hard time finding good documentation on model binding in ASP.NET 4.5. Is this really undocumented behavior? Everything works fine, but I have to admit I have had to experiment and search around a lot to figure out how to use model binding because of the poor official documentation. Does anyone know if this is officially supported or not? Or where to find good documentation that I can look through?

Comment: I ran into this today, using an "official" tutorial from MS.  See [Shopping Cart](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/shopping-cart).  Sad day...